# Sweave function in r fails when .Rnw having a chunk with "results" options

Tags: r, sweave

I want to use 'R' script to convert my Sweave file into PDF ultimately.
I learnt that, Sweave(file="TEST.Rnw") is the function that can convert my .Rnw into .tex.

But I see a strange issue when I use that on my .Rnw file that has a code chunk like this:

```
    <<results='asis', comment=NA, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
    ...
    @
```

This is the error, I am getting:

```
Error in match.arg(options$results, c("verbatim", "tex", "hide")) :
'arg' should be one of "verbatim", "tex", "hide"
```

Please note that Sweave()  works when I change results='tex'. But that does not help me as  I have some xtable content that needs to be coming in latex. The simple question, therefore, is, when the option results='asis' works on RStudio (Complile PDF), why it does not with Sweave function call? Am I missing something?

Any lights on this will be highly appreciated... Thanks, in advance.

Regards,
Tharma

Comment: Package `knitr` uses "asis" while `Sweave` uses "tex".

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I just realized that using 'knitr::knit2pdf' does the magic!

Answer (score 2):

Go to RStudio > Preferences > Sweave

Set "Weave Rnw files using:" to "knitr" and make sure that you have knitr installed (`install.packages("knitr")`)

Answer (score -4):

Try to pass `result=tex` (without quotes).

Comment: What does this add to the problem ? Asker already stated it works with `result='tex'`, but that's not the question at all. Moreover without the quote the interpreter will error out if there's no variable named `tex` in the scope.